# Why Kotlin 1.6.x uses kotlinx-coroutines 1.5.2 by default

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I use Kotlin 1.6.20 in my Gradle project and It uses dependency kotlinx-coroutines 1.5.2 by default.

*build.gradle.kts*

```
plugins {
    ...
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.20"
}

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm")
}
```

But latest version is 1.6.1.

`implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm:1.6.1")`

Stability reason?

Comment: I don't think the Kotlin plugin takes any part in choosing the version of coroutines lib. Normally, you should always specify the version of dependencies manually and if you don't then Gradle throws error. If it didn't fail for you then I suspect the version was chosen from some other dependency or you specified this version in another place. Execute `./gradlew dependencies` to see what is going on here.